# How will GenAI be different than ChatGPT?

Tags: chatgpt

I am trying to determine if GenAI will be a replacement for ChatGPT for questions about programming and computer science. It seems more likely the two tool will augment each other, but if so, how?

Comment: I think this should probably be on https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to [genai.se]. What do you understand about GenAI and ChatGPT? What made you consider comparing GenAI and ChatGPT, given that they belong to the same category?

Comment: Does "GenAI" here mean this site, or generative AI in general?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to determine if GenAI will be a replacement for ChatGPT for questions about programming and computer science.

No, it was explained in the article [Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/):

> GenAI Stack Exchange will serve as a place for a community that is centered around knowledge sharing: posting questions and answers about things like prompt engineering, getting the most out of AI, and staying on top the rapidly evolving ecosystem of GenAI tools.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: It's inappropriate to compare GenAI and ChatGPT when answering programming questions, as they belong to separate categories.

---

It's hard to provide a definitive answer to this question as it's unclear what it means about GenAI and ChatGPT as both terms are novel; their origin might be attributed to a very specific community, but due to the hype abound, both terms have spread to the general public. There are a lot of myths, misunderstandings and misinformation.

If we accept Wikipedia as a good source for general knowledge, we might have to start by reading [Generative artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_artificial_intelligence), [Synthetic media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_media) and [ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/ChatGPT). The first two articles have suggestions notice that both articles can be merged.

According to Wikipedia, *Generative artificial intelligence* is a type of intelligence of machines or software instead of human intelligence. At the same time, *ChatGPT* is a chatbot developed by OpenAI.

In other words, *GenAI* is a concept that belongs to abstract thinking, initially used by Artificial Intelligence scientific and engineering communities. At the same time, *ChatGPT* is concrete as people can use it through easy-to-get consumer devices like personal computers and smartphones.

Confusion occurs as *GenAI* and *ChatGPT* are used more frequently in mass communications where the words are not chosen carefully to have a precise message but chosen to have more viewers looking to make a content piece viral to produce immediate revenue.